# Quarterly calendar view sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, view, sharepoint-calendar

I need to create quarterly/three months view in calendar?

*Note: I am not able to use Visual Studio.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are no OOTB solutions for this and the ones available on internet are mostly for money, I came up with kind of a solution.

I created regular calendar monthly view. Put that calendar list in web part page twice. first WP I left intact, a regular calendar view, but at the second I changed view to all events.
Than changed all events view to filter and show only if start date is greater than [today]-30 and start date is less than [today]+30.

If anyone knows proper solution to show three months view in calendar please share solution.